# How do I check if the mentioned user has Administrator permission?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

The code that I provided below still mutes the mentioned user even though he/she has the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission. Also, how can I check if the moderator is trying to mute the server's owner.

```
const mutee = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])

if(mutee.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("Cannot mute this user.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should replace :
`mutee.member.hasPermission`
with simply :
`mutee.hasPermission`, since `mutee` is already your GuildMember :)